# How can I rewrite a URL to pass requests to a custom method via AJAX? (I can't use admin-ajax.php)

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, ajax

I have to build a WordPress plugin which gives out HTML for an AJAX call. However, because of the server environment I cannot use the traditional `admin-ajax.php`.

Someone told me that I could build a custom page using url-rewrite ex: `/my-ajax-calls/`

So when I send a request to that page it would be:

```
jQuery.get("/my-ajax-calls/param1/param2/",...);
```

Then I could use `param1` & `param2` and give the appropriate HTML.

I know how to build plugins, how do I rewrite the URL to connect it with a method that generates the HTML?

Comment: Please reformat your Q (you have wysiwyg editor buttons on top). And also please don't use dialect words like "becoz". This is a public page and not private chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply target to a custom file when using [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Just - in the third argument-array - set `ajax_url` to whatever file you want to target.